# Create a form with PHP and process the data within the same script

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible to create a form with PHP and process this form with the same script  it was created by.

I tried this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['GO'])) {

echo "Hola Mundo";
}
?>

<body>
<form  action="procesarFormula.php" method="post">


     <b>Nombre</b> <input type="text" name="nombre"><br/><br/>
    <input  type="submit" value="GO"> 

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I click the submit button I get the `Object not found` error.
Note the script is saved in a file called procesarFormula.php

Any help please ?

Comment: Sure but `if(isset($_POST['GO'])) {...}` will never "go".

Comment: try `if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){ `  since you do not have an input named GO. but you do have an input named "nombre"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<input  type="submit" value="GO">
```

To

```
<input  type="submit" name="GO">
```

Otherwise, `$_POST["GO"]` will never be set

Answer (score 0):

You should include a 'name' attribute for that submit input. The reason is your POST global variable is an array that holds all the key{name} value{value} pair for all your posted inputs. So in your code, you're calling the key, but you only have the value set.